# Is there a way to use ActionView Helpers in Coffeescript/Javascript in Rails 4?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

For example, if I want to do something like in kites.js.coffee:

```
  = select_tag :kite, options_for_select([["kite1","1"],["kite2","2"]], selected: nil), {class: 'form-control', name: "kite[tail]"}
```

where KITE_OPTIONS = [["kite1","1"],["kite2","2"], etc.]

The whole point is to not have to manually write javascript code that reads like:

```
js_variable = "<select>....<option>kite1</option></select>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not do that, if you include ruby code in CofeeScript templates, then you will have a performance overhead by compiling the CofeeScript on every request. That's the reason you don't have an easy way to include ruby code into coffeescript, its intentional to avoid such a thing.

You can serve the javascript variables from your views, and then use them within the coffeeescript template:

```
javascript:
  var options_for_select = '#{options_for_select([["kite1","1"],["kite2","2"]]}';
coffee:
  $(document).ready ->
    alert(options_for_select);
```